# I think there is an error in this solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been trying to reconcile this solution with my work for hours now. Could someone please help me confirm whether the solution provided below is incorrect?

I get a solution of X > -3/2, the provided solution is X < 3/2

[image: I am too new to embed images]

Comment: That was my question initially. The solution shown is my professor's. My calculations do not do this. I've been trying to figure out where she got the 3x for hours now.

Comment: She made a typo.  $\frac 58 - \frac x3 = \frac {3*5 - 8*x}{3*5}$.  Once that mistake happened all things that followed will not be correct.

Comment: @fleablood, denominator should be 3*8, not 3*5.

Comment: Like I said.  Once a mistake happens... things.  follow.  the professor made an error.  *I* made an error.  Neither of us got the right answer because of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is incorrect. In the first passage both sides of $$\frac 58-\frac x3>\frac18-\frac23x$$ are multiplied by $24$. But in the proposed solution "$-\frac x3$" becomes "$-8\cdot 3x$", instead of "$-8x$".

Comment: I am most grateful for a confirmation that the solution provided is in error and my own calculations are correct. It is a relief to my aching brain.

Comment: Could you provide for me the rule which causes 12>-8x to become x>-3/2. My remaining confusion with this problem is that although I can see that this is true I cannot extrapolate exactly the procedure where the x changes sides and the signs remain the same.

Comment: @HeidiGood, the rule is... whenever you multiply or divide by a negative number, the less than sign turns into greater than, and vice versa... 12>-8x. divide both sides by -8, so we change signs 12/-8 < x. -3/2<x.  or x>-3/2.

Comment: Ah.. and then the sign changes back to the original only because we flipped it to read the X value the other way around. Thank you. That will also help me a lot.

Comment: If you want to get down to brass tacks.  $a < b$ means $a + x < b + x$ no matter what $x$ is (positive, negative or zero).  So $a < b$ means $a - a < b - a$ means $0 < b-a$ means $0 -b < b - a -b $ means $-b < -a$ means $-a > -b$.  So "taking negatives flip the sign".  We also know if $n > 0$ and $a < b$ then $na < nb$.  This is because... well, it's an axiom.  But if you think of $n$ as an positive integer it is $na = a+a+a+..< b+b+b+.... =nb$.  For other reals... well, "it follows" so $a < b => an < bn => -na > -nb$.  That's hand-wavy but I hope it helps.  "negative flip" it's a rule.

Comment: More explanations on why an inequality symbol flips from division by a negative: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543722/why-does-the-sign-have-to-be-flipped-in-this-inequality

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\frac{5}{8} - \frac{x}{3} &> \frac{1}{8} -\frac{2x}{3} && \text{Multiply by } 24 \\
15 -8x &> 3 -16x \\
12 &> -8x && \text{Divide by $-8$ which changes the sign}\\
-\frac{3}{2} &< x
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You have a mistake at the first step:

$$
\frac{5}{8}-\frac{x}{3}>\frac{1}{8}-\frac{2x}{3} \iff 5\cdot 3 \color{red}{-8\cdot x} >3 -8\cdot(2x) 
$$

so the final step becomes 
$$
12 >-8x
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple let me show you

$5/8-x/3>1/8-2x/3$

now we interchange

$-x/3+2x/3>1/8-5/8$

$x/3>-4/8$

$x>-12/8$

$x>-3/2$

get it

just see this once
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2F8%E2%88%92x%2F3%3E1%2F8%E2%88%922x%2F3