# Why is $n>\frac{-\log 13}{\log 0.8}=n \log0.8<-\log13$

Tags: logarithms

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious here but in my text book, dealing with a logarithmic inequality, the $<$ is seemingly switched arbitrarily:

$$
  1-0.8^n < \frac{12}{13}
$$

$$
  0.8^n < \frac{1}{13}
$$

$$
  n \log0.8 < -\log13
$$

$$
  n > \frac{-\log13}{\log0.8}
$$

I saw this type of rearranging earlier in the book and thought it might be a typo but seeing it a second time confirms there's something I'm not understanding. Why has the sign changed although we have simply divided both sides by $\log0.8$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the inequality right in the second line? I'd say that $0.8^n>\frac{1}{13}$ and, therefore, that all subsequent inequalities should also be reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\log 0.8$ is negative, and dividing by a negative number reverses inequalities (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543722/why-does-the-sign-have-to-be-flipped-in-this-inequality)).

---

More generally, you have that $\log 1 = 0$ because $e^{0} = 1$. So when $0<x<1$ you have that $\log x <0$.

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks! Will mark accepted when I can. While you're here, any chance of letting me know why my title is not formatting correctly? :)

Comment: @HenryCooper You accidentally had an `)` where you needed an `}`, for the fraction that is. I've corrected it for you.

Comment: Hero, thanks, much appreciated!